# Pages 5.5 isn't opening Pages document created by the previous version

Tags: macos, pages

I have a very important document that I wrote in Pages (the version prior to Pages 5.5). Now on Yosemite and Pages 5.5, I can't even open the document.

The Pages document is an attachment in GMail. It is not stored on iCloud.

Error Message
"FileName" Can't be opened

And I don't have iWork 09 anymore.

How to solve that?

Comment: Is the document stored on your device or in iCloud? Also, what is the error message you receive when going to open it. Lastly, what year mac are you on, if you originally had a pages 09 (v 4.) you should still have your old pages app in your applications folder under iWork09 folder.

Comment: Have you tried saving it to your hard drive first, then opening it?

Comment: @Macasourous Of course. That is what I'm doing.

Comment: At that point it appears the file has been corrupted. I have two or three files showing that message myself. But mine are on iCloud Drive. When a file is not corrupted pages will say "this doc was made with an earlier version of pages. Upgrade Doc?" and then you can open it, but I understand what you are saying. I once had success opening one at iCloud.com online pages beta, where it read the file.

Yeah, I just tried it again, go to iCloud.com, login, click on the pages beta and upload your pages file that won't open. It may just work for you. I was just able to open an old file of mine.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it again, go to iCloud.com, login, click on the pages beta and upload your pages file that won't open. It may just work for you. I was just able to open an old file of mine.

Comment: I will when I'm home again. Thank you for your kind help. I will update the post if I found something.

Comment: I've posted a solution for all three iWork programs at this Ask Different question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176409 .