# New version of Keynote won't open old versions

Tags: macos, keynote, iwork

When using a newer version of iWork software such as on Yosemite to open older documents and presentations, Pages reports "This document can’t be opened because it’s too old. To open it, save it with Pages ’09 first." and Keynote reports "This presentation can’t be opened because it’s too old. To open it, save it with Keynote ’09 first." How can I open these files without finding and installing an old version of iWork?

**Edit**: The latest update, version 6.6 (2550) (as of October 16, 2015) opens Keynote '06 and '08 version files. I verified this on a file from 2007 and it works properly.

Comment: Welcome - try not to post identical answers to two questions. When that happens, we typically close one as a [duplicate of the other](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167073/) in cases where truly the same answer applies to both situations. Let's make this about keynote and link it to the pages answer. That answer as well should be about pages and not keynote.

Comment: @bmike Thanks; if you're going to edit answers, though, please double-check they have the correct content.

Comment: You can revert it, but the edit was more a suggestion leaving it obviously broken so that you'd hopefully come back and fix it. Don't mistake moderation for being a subject matter expert. :-) I did uproot just about all the relevant posts since I appreciate your breathing new life into this issue and alerting us to the duplication of questions. (the beauty of wiki / community editing is that everyone can and does pitch in little efforts to make a polished artifact over time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution requires using Terminal. Do the following:

1. Make a backup copy of your file
2. Open Terminal.app
3. In the Terminal window, type `cd` (that's with a space after the `cd`) then drag your file to the window. It should insert the full path of your file (e.g. `/Users/me/Documents/My\ Great\ File.pages`).
4. Copy and paste the following command as a single line and press <kbd>Return</kbd>: `gunzip --stdout index.apxl.gz | sed 's-:version="72007061400"-:version="92008102400"-g' > index.apxl`
5. If you don't see any errors (such as `No such file or directory`), now type `rm index.apxl.gz` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>
6. Type `exit` and press <kbd>Return</kbd> and try to open your file. It may give you a compatibility problem report but should open.

## Explanation

The file `index.apxl.gz` is a compressed XML file that holds information about your document. The command in step 4 uncompresses the file and runs it through a search-and-replace program which looks for the version `72007061400` and replaces it with the version `92008102400` (I don't know what these versions mean but it appears to work). It outputs to an uncompressed version of the file, which is why in step 5 you remove the original, compressed file (iWork will used compressed or uncompressed files).

## Notes

If step 4 gives you a `No such file or directory` error, it's possible the `index.apxl` or `index.apxl` file is uncompressed, in which case you can replace the step 4 command with `sed 's-:version="72007061400"-:version="92008102400"-g' index.apxl | gzip > index.apxl.gz`, and step 5 with `rm index.apxl`.

This solution could be adapted to an Automator action by someone motivated.

## Source

This method is adapted from a comment on [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+StefanUrbanek/posts/LKkGeEoPUzA).

Comment: Sounds like this would be a great little AppleScript droplet or app.

Comment: D'oh! Copy and paste error. Fixing.

Comment: Latest update (2015-10-16) says it opens Keynote '06 and '08 version files.